# Local clone of a github fork: How do I keep things synced?

Tags: git, github

1) On github, I forked a repository in order to submit a pull request.

2) Then I cloned the repository to my local computer.

3) Then I created a branch, and I made some changes to one of the files in the repository.

4) Then I thought I needed to sync my local repository with the original repository(the one I forked) before submitting my pull request, so I tried:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/7stud/sinatra.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/7stud/sinatra.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra.github.com.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra.github.com.git (push)

$ git fetch upstream
```

...but I got errors that said there were discrepancies for lots of files.  I did some googling about that, but I wasn't about to go into all the files and start changing things by hand, so I skipped syncing.

5) I managed to push my changes to my github repository, and then submit my pull request.

6) The pull request was accepted, so then I thought I should merge my local branch into my local master, and maybe try syncing again.

7) But I can't even switch into my local branch without getting an error:

```
$ git branch
  improve_readme
* master


$ git checkout improve_readme
.gitignore: needs merge
Gemfile: needs merge
README.md: needs merge
Rakefile: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

What do I need to do to "resolve my current index first"? I was thinking about submitting another pull request.  If the easiest thing to do is to delete my fork on gihub and delete my local clone, then re-fork and re-clone I can do that.

I just tried the following again:

```
$ git fetch upstream
$
```

and I didn't get errors this time, but I also didn't get any output like this:

```
# remote: Counting objects: 75, done.
# remote: Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
# remote: Total 62 (delta 27), reused 44 (delta 9)
# Unpacking objects: 100% (62/62), done.
# From https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY
```

And I still can't switch branches:

```
$ git checkout improve_readme
.gitignore: needs merge
Gemfile: needs merge
README.md: needs merge
Rakefile: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

Here is some more info:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   new file:   CNAME
#   new file:   Gemfile.lock
#   new file:   Thorfile
#   new file:   _config.yml
#   new file:   _includes/README.de.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.es.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.fr.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.hu.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.ja.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.ko.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.pt-br.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.pt-pt.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.ru.html
#   new file:   _includes/README.zh.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-config-file.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-content-for.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-cookies.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-decompile.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-extension.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-json.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-link-header.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-multi-route.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-namespace.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-reloader.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-respond-with.html
#   new file:   _includes/sinatra-streaming.html
#   new file:   _layouts/contrib.html
#   new file:   _layouts/default.html
#   new file:   _layouts/post.html
#   new file:   _posts/2009-01-18-sinatra-0.9.0.markdown
#   new file:   _posts/2009-01-29-we-have-a-faq-now.markdown
#   new file:   _posts/2011-03-03-blog-revived.markdown
#   new file:   _posts/2011-03-03-sinatra-1.2.0.markdown
#   new file:   _posts/2011-07-21-sinatra-loves-dancer.markdown
#   new file:   _posts/2011-09-30-sinatra-1.3.0.markdown
#   new file:   _posts/2013-03-15-sinatra-1.4.0.markdown
#   new file:   about.markdown
#   new file:   api/index.html
#   new file:   blog.html
#   new file:   book.html
#   new file:   changes.html
#   new file:   configuration.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/config_file.html
#   new file:   contrib/content_for.html
#   new file:   contrib/cookies.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/decompile.html
#   new file:   contrib/extension.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/index.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/json.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/link_header.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/multi_route.html
#   new file:   contrib/namespace.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/reloader.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/respond_with.markdown
#   new file:   contrib/streaming.markdown
#   new file:   contributing.markdown
#   new file:   css/legend.css
#   new file:   css/print.css
#   new file:   css/syntax.css
#   new file:   documentation.markdown
#   new file:   example.markdown
#   new file:   extensions-wild.markdown
#   new file:   extensions.markdown
#   new file:   faq.markdown
#   new file:   feed.xml
#   new file:   images/favicon.ico
#   new file:   images/legend.gif
#   new file:   images/link-out.gif
#   new file:   images/logo.png
#   new file:   index.html
#   new file:   intro-de.html
#   new file:   intro-es.html
#   new file:   intro-fr.html
#   new file:   intro-hu.html
#   new file:   intro-ja.html
#   new file:   intro-ko.html
#   new file:   intro-pt-br.html
#   new file:   intro-pt-pt.html
#   new file:   intro-ru.html
#   new file:   intro-zh.html
#   new file:   intro.html
#   new file:   one-oh-faq.markdown
#   new file:   testing.markdown
#   new file:   wild.markdown
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both added:         .gitignore
#   both added:         Gemfile
#   both added:         README.md
#   both added:         Rakefile
#
```

I guess that is why git won't let me switch branches.  I don't understand where those changes came from.  According to:

https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork

> Fetch the branches and their respective commits from the upstream repository. Commits to master will be stored in a local branch, upstream/master.

But I don't have any local branch called upstream/master:

```
$ git branch
  improve_readme
* master
```

Did the upstream changes to master automatically merge with my local master?

Comment: `git branch`, by default, only lists local branches. To list remote-tracking branches (e.g. `upstream/master`), you must use `git branch -r`. To list all branches, use `git branch -a`.

Comment: @Jubobs, What about the quote I posted?  It says `$ git fetch upstream` will create a *local* branch.   Also, where did all the changes come from that are listed by `$ git status`?  I changed only one file, and it was on the local branch named improve_readme.  I made no changes to the local master branch.

Comment: For what it's worth, in any normal (non-mirror) setup, `git fetch` does not write to anything under `refs/heads/`, only `refs/remotes/`.  While these `refs/remotes/` branches are physically local they're normally called "remote branches".  (That's not where the "new file" and "unmerged" bits are from though.)

Comment: @Jubobs, @torek, After you fork a repo, then clone the repo to your local computer, are you supposed to do `git init`? Or maybe `git commit -a -m "Something"`?

Comment: You (generally) wouldn't do `git init` in a repo you just cloned, but if you want to contribute to it, you would do one or more commits, yes.

Comment: @Jubobs, I thought maybe that's where all the files came from that `git status` listed.  What should I do know?  Delete everything?

Comment: @Jubobs, I ended up doing: 1) `$ git fetch upstream` (I got no output that said git was downloading anything) 2) `$ git add .` 3) `$ git commit -a -m "Committing a bunch of stuff--from whence it came I know not."` 4) `$ git checkout master` (I was already on master branch.) 5) `$ git merge upstream/master` 6) `$ git push origin master`. Now my forked repo on github says: This branch is 672 commits ahead, 1 commit behind sinatra:master. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

There's a really awesome tool called [hub](https://github.com/github/hub). It hooks in standard git methods with Github api calls to make things like this super simple.

I'd recomend reading up on how git works with remotes, but if you want an easy way of rebasing sinatra/master into your branch do this:

For example:

I clone your repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/7stud/sinatra.git
cd sinatra/
```

I open a pull-request onto your repo from Sinatra:

```
https://github.com/7stud/sinatra/pull/2
```

I then use the hub am tool to make a merge from the downloaded diff:

```
git am -3 https://github.com/7stud/sinatra/pull/2
```

It basically does all the hard work for you.